# Confused about .net MVC View Models and Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

So, I've read a bit about .net and MVC. I remember reading something that suggested using ViewModels in MVC. This would help lessen the desire to have the view messing with data that should be controlled by the controller.

I thought this is what is referred to by the MVVM pattern. Evidently after looking at that, the implementation actually does away with controllers altogether. Not exactly what I want to do.

Is it still legit to use a ViewModel in my case? Is it better practice or just unnecessary work? Where would you put your ViewModels directory/namespace at? Under the Models directory?

Is it legit for Models to know about ViewModels? For example, you have a Model Return a ViewModel to the controller?

Comment: I am on a asp.net mvc project that use jqgrid . The jqgrid requires specific request and response data structures. So I created specific view models to work with the jqgrid.  For simple input data (to an controller action) such as simple value types, Dictionary types, IEnumerable types, the asp.net mvc can usually understand how to "bind" to those data.

Comment: Wanted to add a reference to this, but not sure it qualifies under any specific answer, so I'll drop it here: http://freshbrewedcode.com/joshbush/2012/03/05/mass-assignment-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models and ViewModels are different.  Don't confuse the ViewModel with the MVVM pattern.

The use of a view model can make the interaction between model and view more simple. A model can sometimes be over complicated having other model objects as members, which could have model objects as member etc..

By using a view model you have a good way to simplify what the view deals with. This will also filter down what can be seen in intellisense, so if you have different people developing the models than those working on the views, creating a simple view model can make it much easier for those just dealing with the UI.

Comment: So would you put the ViewModels namespace under the Model namespace? Is this something that should be somewhere else?

Comment: It doesn't matter, that's up to you, in my projects I usually create a ViewModel folder.

Comment: @Walt - Most non-trivial projects place their business and data layers in different projects, this leaves the Models folder in MVC strictly for View Models.  If you are not doing that, then you can just as easily create a ViewModels folder to create a seperation.

Comment: It doesn't matter, and I used to do that.  Now I tend to create more folders like "ViewModels"   "Infrastructure"  and more projects like a "projectname.Data"  and "projectname.Core" and "projectname.Test" etc..  with folders explicitly named making it clear what their purpose in life is.

Answer (score 2):

ViewModels are not by default in MVC projects.  It is something you need to add if you feel it benefits you to couple View to a Model "easier"

http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications

The concept of the ViewModel isn't just for ASP.NET MVC, as you'll see references to ViewModels throughout the web in articles and blog posts about the MVC, MVP, and MVVM patterns. Those posts and articles can center around any number of technologies such as ASP.NET, Silverlight, WPF, or MVC... This post will investigate ViewModels as they apply to the world of ASP.NET MVC.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx

Comment: So a Model can return a View Model to the controller? For some reason I was thinking that it should remain oblivious to view data and that the controller should be the one to send Model data to a ViewModel, then pass it to a view.

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns in my opinion are not rigid concepts, but rather guidelines that help you architect your application better.  The Model-View-ViewModel(MVVM) design pattern stems from WPF, where there is a very robust Bata Binding framework that facilitated the pattern.  The idea is that you have business data in your model, but since there are often view specific data(i.e the currently selected item in a tree control) that didn't belong in the model, you created view model objects that wraps your model, but the view models also contained view specific state data.  So your views can bind to the view models instead of the model objects directly, thus keeping the models clean(easy to test, maintain etc).

Asp.net MVC is different in that the databinding in the Views is nowhere near as powerful as it is in WPF.  In WPF you could actually implement much of your GUI and model data interaction through databinding, which made the view models useful.  But in Asp.net MVC your controllers are designed to handle this, and since the databinding is close to non existant I just don't see the value of having view model wrappers around your model objects in Asp.net MVC.

Comment: You may not see the value, but it's there. For one, if you use ASP.NET MVC's build in validation via data annotations, it's much cleaner to have a separate view model that is decorated with validation attributes, rather than polluting your domain objects. Also, you can tailor view models to specific view requirements, sort of like a DTO for your view.

Comment: @Chris - do you think entity-level security implementation belongs to the view model layer rather than domain models ? Currently I am considering adding security id fields to each of my entity, but it seems to "pollute" my domain ( because if I use a different security provider or framework , I might need to change all those secruity specific fields in my domain entities.

Comment: @Chris - I wondered about the ViewModel/Model question because in .Net, at least, you can make your ViewModel/Model a parameter for the action methods in your controller. Then .Net auto populates the values from form submissions or regular requests. If you use a ViewModel you have to go an extra step every time to get the data from your ViewModel into your Model. On the flip-side, your action method might require data represented by multiple Models so a ViewModel would be very useful in that situation.

Comment: @Walt - the issue of mapping view models to models is why things like AutoMapper were invented. The automatic binding of form properties to view model properties that ASP.NET MVC also works if you pass a domain model object in the action method parameters, so long as the domain object properties line up with the form field names, but again, you're exposing intricate domain details to the view that may not be necessary. Again, to clarify, I generally think of ViewModels as nothing mroe than DTO objects for the view, with maybe a few presentation layer specifics thrown in).

Comment: @dan_l, I'm not sure exactly how your code is structured, but if you're concerned about changing providers later, then your security specific fields seem like a perfect candidate for further abstraction. You could perhaps create an ISecurityInfo implementation that is attached to each object and have an ISecurityProvider implementation that does the necessary security checks. If you need to change frameworks or security providers later, you could then easily do so.