# Is there a design pattern to standardise the display of multiple models into a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, interface, viewmodel

I've tinkered with derived classes, interfaces and viewmodels, but I haven't been able to create quite what I need.

Say we're building a CMS with the following models:

**ArticleItem**

- Title
- Summary
- Content

**NewsItem**

- Headline
- PublishDate
- Summary
- Content

**EventItem**

- EventTitle
- StartDate
- EndDate
- Content

I'm looking for a way to standardise  the display of these into one format / view (e.g. so we can  display them all in the same RSS feed). The standardized view might be called **HTMLItem** and have 3 fields:

- Title
- Summary
- Content

The **ArticleItem** would translate directly to the **HTMLItem**, that's straightforward.

For the **NewsItem** I would like to join the PublishDate and the first 100 characters of the content to create Summary field of **HTMLItem**.

For the **EventItem** I would like to combine the StartDate and EndDate to create the Summary field of **HTMLItem**.

Ultimately I'm looking for the easiest, most efficient way to be able to pass the 3 models into a single view that has been designed to display **HTMLItem**. My best shot so far has been to create a 'convertor' class for each model, but I can't help feeling that there is a better way to do this.

Any experience, expertise and advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a ViewModel with the standarized properties and a constructor for each specialized class:

```
public class HtmlItemViewModel {
    //Properties
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Summary {get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}

    //Constructor inside HtmlItemViewModel for each one of the specialized classes:
    public HtmlItemViewModel(ArticleItem item)
    {
        this.Title = item.Title;
        this.Summary = item.Summary;
        this.Content = item.Content;
    }

    public HtmlItemViewModel(NewsItem item)
    {
        this.Title = item.Headline;
        this.Summary = String.Format("{0} - {1}", item.PublishDate, item.Summary.Substring(0,1000));
        this.Content = item.Content;
    }

    public HtmlItemViewModel(EventItem item)
    {
        this.Title = item.EventTitle;
        this.Summary = String.Format("{0} - {1}", item.StartDate, item.EndDate);
        this.Content = item.Content;
    }
}
```

Then, on the method you use for your RSS Feed simply pass each entity to the constructor on each individual query. Like this:

```
//Example controller
public class RssController : Controller {
    public ActionResult GetRssFeed(){
        //Assuming you have a service for each item type
        var articleList = ArticleService.GetArticles().Select(s => new HtmlItemViewModel(s));
        var newsItemList = NewsItemService.GetNewsItems().Select(s => new HtmlItemViewModel(s));
        var eventItemList = EventItemService.GetEvents().Select(s => new HtmlItemViewModel(s));

        articleList.AddRange(newsItemList);
        articleList.AddRange(eventItemList);

        return articleList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I think this is the approach I'm going to take. The constructor for each class appeals to my inner gadget man.

Comment: @Forty-Two : Your answer was also very helpful, with regard to mapping options and data annotations. Acually, I didn't realise they could be used on a viewmodel :-$  Many thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425982/confused-about-net-mvc-view-models-and-models) Pattern in your project

> Models and ViewModels are different. Don't confuse the ViewModel with
>   the MVVM pattern.
>
> The use of a view model can make the interaction between model and
>   view more simple. A model can sometimes be over complicated having
>   other model objects as members, which could have model objects as
>   member etc..
>
> By using a view model you have a good way to simplify what the view
>   deals with. This will also filter down what can be seen in
>   intellisense, so if you have different people developing the models
>   than those working on the views, creating a simple view model can make
>   it much easier for those just dealing with the UI.

Comment: Just to clarify (as a c# noob), that would be best implemented with some kind of mapping system either as it's own class or in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The simple and most common solution to this is to create a composite view model class.  This can be a composed class (containing references to your domain models), or a flattened class, referencing properties from each class individually.

So you could do this:

```
public class HtmlItemViewModel
{
  public ArticleItem ArticleItem {get; set;}
  public NewsItem NewsItem {get; set;}
  public EventItem EventItem {get; set;}
}
```

Or this:

```
public class HtmlItemViewModel
{
  //Article Item Properties
  public string ArticleTitle {get; set;}
  public string ArticleContent {get; set;}
  public string ArticleSummary {get; set;}
  //News Item Properties
  public string Headline {get; set;}
  public DateTime PublishDate {get; set;}
  public string NewsItemSummary {get; set;}
  public string NewsItemContent {get; set;}
  //Event Item Properties
  public string EventTitle {get; set;}      
  public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}    
  public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
  public string EventContent {get; set;}
}
```

Then, whichever way you choose to construct the view model, you will map the view model properties to the domain model(s) in the controller.  You can do this mapping manually

```
HtmlItemViewModel.ArticleTitle = ArticleItem.ArticleTitle;
//and so on...
```

Or you can use a third party tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

I tend to favor the flattened view model in most scenarios as it allows me to only send the data I need, no more, no less.  And it also allows me to put my data annotations for input validation on the view model instead of the domain model.